# Mock an external endpoint in NodeJs by Moxios

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, moxios

I am trying to mock an external endpoint of `Twilio` in the unit test by `Moxios` library. I am also using `SuperTest` library to provide the exceptions of the test.

My internal endpoint which is called by Front-end is:

```
router.get('/twilio', async (req, res, next) => {
   const result = await validatePhoneNumber(68848239, 'SG');
   res.status(200).json(result);
});
```

and `validatePhoneNumber` is a function which calls the external endpoint by `Axios` which I am trying to mock and not to call the actual endpoint during the test:

```
const validatePhoneNumber = async (phone, code) => {
  const endpoint = `https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/${phone}?CountryCode=${code}`;

  try {
    const { status } = await axios.get(endpoint, {
      auth: {
        'username': accountSid,
        'password': authToken
      }
    });

    console.log('twilio', phone, status);

    return {
      isValid: status === 200,
      input: phone
    };
  } catch (error) {
    const { response: { status } } = error;

    if (status === 404) {
      // The phone number does not exist or is invalid.
      return {
        input: phone,
        isValid: false
      };
    } else {
      // The service did not respond corrctly.
      return {
        input: phone,
        isValid: true,
        concerns: 'Not validated by twilio'
      };
    }
  }
};
```

And my the unit test code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const axios = require('axios');
const moxios = require('moxios');

describe('some-thing', () => {

    beforeEach(function () {
        moxios.install()
    })

    afterEach(function () {
        moxios.uninstall()
    })

    it('stub response for any matching request URL', async (done) => {

        // Match against an exact URL value
        moxios.stubRequest(/https:\/\/lookup.twilio.*/, {
            status: 200,
            responseText: { "isValid": true, "input": 68848239 }
        });

        request(app)
            .get('/twilio')
            .expect(200, { "isValid": true, "input": 68848239 }, done);
    });
});
```

If in my case `Moxios` is the right way to mock any external endpoints, I am getting the error below:

```
 Error: Timeout of 3000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (c:\Source\Samples\Twilio\myproject\test\twilio.test.js)
```

I increased the time out to 10000 but still I get a same error.
Appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Vickycoder Yes I found a way. I am using axios-mock-adapter library. https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried different ways but I prefer to go on with `axios-mock-adapter` library to mock any request through `Axios`.

Example:

```
const app = require('../app');
const axios = require('axios');
const request = require('supertest');
const MockAdapter = require('axios-mock-adapter');


describe('Valid phone number', () => {
    it('Should return data from response', (done) => {

        let mockAdapter = new MockAdapter(axios);

        mockAdapter.onGet(twilioEndpoint)
            .reply(200);

        request(app)
            .post('/api/validation')
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .send(JSON.stringify(configuration))
            .expect(200, { "isValid": true, "input": "68848239" }, done);
    });
});
```

More information [here](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter)